# QGIS cannot find transformation grid

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, proj

When I open an existing QGIS project I get an error bar at the top of the mapping window stating that some data cannot be projected (see below).
[image]

I can click on the details button and I get the following message.

[image]

I have located and download the required us_noaa_WO.tif file.

If I click on the *Install from Folder* button I can navigate to the downloaded file and select the file but then I get this error:

[image]

In response I have copied the file to the listed directory ( /home/gerry/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/proj/us_noaa_WO.tif).   but I still get the error when I open my QGIS projects.

Thinking this was a Linux folder permissions problem I have changed the permissions of this directory using `chmod -R 777`.  Still, closing and opening QGIS did not solve the problem.

How do I install or use the ua_noaa_WO.tif file in QGIS 3.10?  I am using QGIS 3.10 on Ubuntu Linux 20.04.

Seeing the comments from @Ben W I have updated to QGIS 3.24.  I still have the same issue.

Seeing the comment from @HeikkiVesanto - I can confirm the file is located at /home/gerry/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/proj/us_noaa_WO.tif.  I can confirm that the directory has had the permissions changed to me (user).  I can also confirm that the tif file has read/write permissions set to me (user) and not root.

I have downgraded QGIS to 3.22 LTS and still have the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Looks like this bug: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35212 and was fixed by this PR: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/35536 Updating should fix the problem.

Comment: Were you able to copy the file into the folder after setting chmod -R 777?

Comment: Updating, changing versions to 3.24, then downgrading to 3.22 have no effect on the error message.